# How to include a XML layout file inside a Java Jar file

Tags: java, android, xml, jar

I want to include a XML layout file inside my Java Jar file, which i want to use it for Android.  I am trying to do something like this in my library jar file.

```
public class Library {

    Activity activity;

    public Library(Activity activity){ 
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void ABC() {
        Toast.makeText(activity,"ABC started",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        istream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/layout/activity.xml");
        // xAxis is inside my activity.xml file
        TextView tvX= (TextView)this.activity.findViewById(R.id.xAxis);
    }
}
```

But when i imported above jar file in my below android application and used like this, it is showing error 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.library.R$id at com.example.library.Library.ABC".

I am really not getting what is the problem?

```
public class CheckLibrary extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.check_library);
        Library lib = new Library(this);
        lib.ABC();
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot package resources to jar.

Comment: @Raghunandan   is there any other method to package jar with XML?

Comment: i do not know any other way or workarounds. sorry

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to include resources in a Java .jar. That's the reason why even the support library that has resources does not come as a jar but as a library project.

Just change your project to be a library project. More info on them can be found in the docs: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Comment: Update: Since the release of Android Studio, there now is an Android archive format called .aar that allows to include resources as well. Just google it.